# TSQL Rewrite UNION into JOIN

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, union

I'm new to SQL and I'm trying to rewrite this query so that it uses a join instead of a union

```
DECLARE @user VARCHAR(255) = 'jSmith'
DECLARE @dept VARCHAR(255) = 'produce'

SELECT DISTINCT A.*
FROM goals A
INNER JOIN managers B ON B.name = @user
WHERE @user IN (A.userName,A.managerUserName)
AND dept = @dept
AND yr = '2016'
UNION   
SELECT DISTINCT A.*
FROM goals A
INNER JOIN managers C ON C.name = @user
INNER JOIN committedGoals B ON A.goalID = B.goalID
WHERE dept LIKE @dept + '%'
AND yr = '2016'
```

Comment: Why do you want to change that to a join?

Comment: The goal would be to store it in a view as I am currently writing this query in a String. I would like to accomplish something like this: `SELECT * FROM myView WHERE @user IN (A.userName,A.managerUserName)
AND dept = @dept
AND yr = '2016'`

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly the same because you've restricted the second part of the query to records that contain a record in committedGoals, but if you always have a record, then this might work for you:

```
SELECT g.*
FROM goals g
LEFT JOIN managers m
  ON g.managerUserName=m.name
WHERE dept LIKE @dept + '%'
AND yr='2016'
AND (g.managerUserName=@user OR m.name=@user)
```